# loquacious NHibernate, joined-subclass equivalent?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am converting some old XML based NHibernate mappings to the newer 'loquacious' approach. (ClassMapping) Everything was going just great until I came upon this little guy...

```
...
<joined-subclass name="CheckinRecord" table="Checkins">
<key column="TransactionID"/>
</joined-subclass>
...
```

I can't figure out an equivalent, and of course the docs for NH are lacking to say the least.  How can I express my joined-subclass in a class mapping, or otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this article](http://notherdev.blogspot.com/2012/01/mapping-by-code-inheritance.html) - joined-subclass strategy is called "Table per class" there.

Generally, your mapping class should inherit from `JoinedSubclassMapping<T>`, you'll then have 
 `Key` method available for `<key>` equivalent.